# Running several 'exec' in a ruby loop

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, exec

I'm scanning a folder for audio files and converting them to mp3.
Works great in RUBY.
However, once the first transcoding is done, it stops the whole loop

Here's a breakdown of my code process.

```
def scanFolder
  # lots of code above to get folder list, check for incorrect files etc..
  audioFileList.each {
    |getFile|

    exec_command = "ffmpeg #{getFile} #{newFileName}"
    exec exec_command
  }
end
```

What's happening is that it's transcoding the first file it finds, then it stops the whole function. Is there a way to force it to continue?

The ffmpeg does run and finish correctly at the moment, so it's not breaking anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[exec](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) replaces the current process by running the given command. Example:

```
2.0.0-p598 :001 > exec 'echo "hello"'
hello
shivam@bluegene:$
```

You can see how `exec` replaces the irb with system `echo` which then exits automatically.

Therefore try using [system](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead. Here the same example using `system`:

```
2.0.0-p598 :003 >   system 'echo "hello"'
hello
 => true 
2.0.0-p598 :004 >
```

You can see I am still in irb and its not exited after executing the command.

This makes your code as follows:

```
def scanFolder
  # lots of code above to get folder list, check for incorrect files etc..
  audioFileList.each {
    |getFile|

    exec_command = "ffmpeg #{getFile} #{newFileName}"
    system exec_command
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Along with shivam's answer about using `system`, the `spawn` method may also be useful here:

http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.5/Process.html#method-c-spawn